# 'The method 'call' was called on null.' in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile

I am trying to extract a value, `touchedIndex`, from a child widget `PieChartWidget` that I have to make a pie chart with a hole in the middle using fl_chart, into its parent widget `Co2Tracker` to allow me to create some text in the middle of the pie chart that changes when a segment of the pie chart is pressed. This returns an error but everything works visually other than the pie chart segments no longer expand.To make debugging easier I replaced the `setState(){isTouched = isTouchedNew}` with `print(isTouchedNew)` but this still returns the error below, however, the pie chart now expands.

[PieChart example](https://pasteboard.co/JkzsWEI.png)

When using a callback function

```
int isTouched = -1;
setIsTouched(int isTouchedNew) {
  print(isTouchedNew);
}
```

integrated within a stateful widget I get an output of

```
════════ Exception caught by gesture ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The method 'call' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: call(-1)
```

parent main page

```
class Co2Tracker extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _Co2TrackerState createState() => _Co2TrackerState();
}

class _Co2TrackerState extends State<Co2Tracker> {

  List<String> pieNames = ['Travel', 'Gas', 'Electricity', 'Food shop', 'Water',];

  int isTouched = -1;
  double radiusNormal = 60;
  double centerRadius = 50;
  double radiusExpansion = 1.2;

  setIsTouched(int isTouchedNew) {
    print(isTouchedNew);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    //double co2 = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: appBarTemplate('CO\u2082 Tracker'),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15),
            child: textStyleTemplateLarge(text: 'Your CO\u2082 emissions today', textColor: Colors.green[400]),
          ),
          AspectRatio(
            aspectRatio: 200/((radiusExpansion*radiusNormal) + centerRadius),
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: Stack(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Center(
                        child: FlatButton(child: textStyleTemplateLarge(text: '70kg', textColor: Colors.black),),
                      ),
                      Center(
                          child: PieChartWidget(radiusNormal: radiusNormal, centerRadius: centerRadius, radiusExpanded: (radiusExpansion*radiusNormal), pieNames: pieNames,),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

child pie chart widget

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fl_chart/fl_chart.dart';

class PieChartWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final double radiusNormal;
  final double radiusExpanded;
  final double centerRadius;
  final double fontSizeNormal;
  final double fontSizeExpanded;
  final List<String> pieNames;
  final Function(int) setIsTouched;

  PieChartWidget({this.radiusNormal, this.radiusExpanded, this.centerRadius, this.fontSizeNormal, this.fontSizeExpanded, this.pieNames, this.setIsTouched});



  @override
  _PieChartWidgetState createState() => _PieChartWidgetState(radiusNormal: radiusNormal, radiusExpanded: radiusExpanded, centerRadius: centerRadius,
    fontSizeNormal: fontSizeNormal, fontSizeExpanded: fontSizeExpanded, pieNames: pieNames, setIsTouched: setIsTouched,);
}

class _PieChartWidgetState extends State<PieChartWidget> {
  int touchedIndex = -1;
  double radiusNormal;
  double radiusExpanded;
  double centerRadius;
  double fontSizeNormal;
  double fontSizeExpanded;
  List<String> pieNames;
  Function(int) setIsTouched;

  _PieChartWidgetState({this.radiusNormal = 50, this.radiusExpanded = 60, this.centerRadius = 40, this.fontSizeNormal = 16, this.fontSizeExpanded = 25,
    this.pieNames, this.setIsTouched,});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PieChart(
      PieChartData(
        sections: pieSections(pieNames),
        borderData: FlBorderData(show: false),
        sectionsSpace: 0,
        centerSpaceRadius: centerRadius,
        pieTouchData: PieTouchData(touchCallback: (pieTouchResponse) {
          setState(() {
            if (pieTouchResponse.touchInput is FlLongPressEnd ||
                pieTouchResponse.touchInput is FlPanEnd) {
              touchedIndex = -1;
            } else {
              touchedIndex = pieTouchResponse.touchedSectionIndex;
            }
          });
          widget.setIsTouched(touchedIndex);
        }),
      ),
    );
  }

-----------------I-think-everything-below-this-is-irrelevant-but-I-could-be-wrong-------------------------------------------

  List<PieChartSectionData> pieSections(List<String> pieNames,) {
    return List.generate(5, (i) {
      final isTouched = i == touchedIndex;
      final double fontSize = isTouched ? 25 : 16;
      final double radius = isTouched ? radiusExpanded : radiusNormal;
      final int colorNumber = (1+i) * 100;
      final List<double> valueList = [20, 10, 10, 20, 30];
      final double total = valueList.fold(0, (a, b) => a+b);
      switch (i) {
        case 0:
          return sectionData(valueList[i], Colors.pink[300], title(isTouched, valueList[i], total, pieNames[i]), radius, fontSize);
        case 1:
          return sectionData(valueList[i], Colors.blue[600], title(isTouched, valueList[i], total, pieNames[i]), radius, fontSize);
        case 2:
          return sectionData(valueList[i], Colors.amber[300], title(isTouched, valueList[i], total, pieNames[i]), radius, fontSize);
        case 3:
          return sectionData(valueList[i], Colors.purple[300], title(isTouched, valueList[i], total, pieNames[i]), radius, fontSize);
        case 4:
          return sectionData(valueList[i], Colors.blue[300], title(isTouched, valueList[i], total, pieNames[i]), radius, fontSize);
        default:
          return null;
      }
    });
  }
  PieChartSectionData sectionData(double value, Color color, String title, double radius, double fontSize,){
    return PieChartSectionData(
      value: value, color: color, title: title, radius: radius,
      titleStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: fontSize, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
    );
  }
  String title(bool isTouched, double value, double total, String title,) {
    return isTouched ? '${double.parse((value/total*100).toStringAsFixed(2))}%' : '$title';
  }
}
```

My thoughts so far have been that maybe it is to do with initialization of variables or maybe this `touchCallback` function from the child page line 43 but no luck so far.
Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when your printing an integer.

`setIsTouched(int isTouchedNew) { print(isTouchedNew); }`

You're supposed to print it like this

```
print("${isTouchedNew}")
```

Comment: Sorry but this just doesn't work ```setIsTouched( int isTouchedNew ) { print("${isTouchedNew}"); }``` the same error is returned and the `"${isTouchedNew}"` is highlinghted with **Avoid using braces in interpolation when not needed.**

Comment: did you try running your code? cuz even with this error "Avoid using braces in interpolation when not needed" your app can run.

Comment: Yeah, I did try it, but it doesn't seem to make a difference. If you want to run the code I think all you would have to do is replace the `appBarTemplate()` with an `AppBar()` widget and the `textStyleTemplateLarge()` template with a `Text()` widget and add a `MaterialApp()` widget at the start.

Comment: ok I think the value that your passing to the function is null

Comment: `setIsTouched` is a function not widget

Comment: this what your using ` widget.setIsTouched(touchedIndex);` try making it `setIsTouched(touchedIndex)` .

Comment: Sorry, it still returns the same result. By the way, do you know what doing widget.something does because I hadn't come across before seeing someone else do it in another post on stack overflow without explaining it? as far as I can tell it takes a function or variable from the parent widget but I really don't know if I'm honest

Comment: widgets are used when you need to define a widget itself as a  function. for instance if you want to use `child:Text("something")`, you can do it by defining a widget `Widget text_widget(){return Text("something ")}` and use it so, `child: text_widget()`. It basically returns a widget itself . You a use to keep your code clean.

Answer (score 0):

Umm..not sure if you tried this,

```
int isTouched = -1;


setIsTouched(int isTouchedNew) {
setState(() {

isTouched=isTouchedNew;
  print(isTouchedNew);
}
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your input. If I understand it correctly, I don't think that you are meant to put print statements within `setState` as you aren't setting making a change to any data that affects any of the on-screen widgets. You could put it after the following "}" but having tried both neither work and putting the `setState(() { isTouched=isTouchedNew; }` back in just stops the pie chart segments from expanding.

Comment: Try placing this line "widget.setIsTouched(touchedIndex)" in the setState() present jst above it.

Comment: The thing is that the function already has a `setState()` within it so you are using a `setState()` within a `setState()`. Having said this, I did try and it doesn't work with this function within the set state as you've done, but it also doesn't work with if you do what you did but without the `setState()` in the original `setIsTouched()` function. I just don't know what to do

Comment: Bro I'm not able to understand it properly, are you able to access the new touchedIndex inside thesetIstoichex()? U tried printing it?

Comment: Yes I've tried printing it. I'm still not able to access the new `touchedIndex` inside the `setIsTouched()`. Essentially I still can't get it to work